# Directly open remote shell with tramp in emacs

Tags: emacs, tramp

I find that the best to run my shells in remote machines in emacs is using TRAMP (using the `ssh` command in a local shell does not work for my needs). However, I only know how to run a TRAMP shell if I first visit a remote file with `C-x C-f` and then do `M-x shell` from that buffer. However, I would like to open a shell in a remote machine, using TRAMP, **before** opening any file on that remote host, but cannot find any explanation on how to do that on my searches. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Please add some additional explanation of what it is your are seeking.  Clearly, you are more advanced that just wanting to know how to ssh into a remote machine from a shell buffer, but that is the direction your question leads the reader.  So, do you want to have a function open a shell buffer and automatically ssh into your remote machine -- so that you are at a prompt and path on the remote server?  Or, do you want a shell mode buffer to already be open, and then just hit an auto-login command?  Do you use `sshpass`?  Would you prefer to enter your password each time?

Comment: Thanks @lawlist ! I reworded the question in hopes that it is more clear. To address your questions: I want some way that lets me make tramp open a remote shell buffer in a machine I specify. The expected behavior is that emacs asks for my password when I try to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tramp comes into play, when the default-directory is remote. So you might change it, as you do with opening a remote file (or directory) in advance.

But you could write a small command like this:

> `(defun my-shell ()
>     (interactive)
>     (let ((default-directory "/ssh:user@host:"))
>       (shell)))`

Then you can call `M-x my-shell`

Comment: If emacs runs on windows and you want to login onto a linux host, you could set with `M-x customize-variable` `explicit-shell-file-name` to `\bin\bash` to avoid missing shell errors.

Comment: @Michael Albinus I've applied that `my-shell` function. It successfully builds a TRAMP connection from my Windows 7 laptop to my Mac computer but after that it exits with `env: C:/msys64/usr/bin/bash.exe: No such file or directory exit` I think it's because in my `.emacs` `tramp-encoding-shell` is set to `C:/msys64/usr/bin/bash.exe` If only I was able to change the value `tramp-encoding-shell` to `/bin/bash` I think it would work out fine. How to do it without hassle? Thanks.

Comment: As always, you could bind it. Like `... (let ((default-directory "/ssh:user@host:")(tramp-encoding-shell "/bin/bash")) (shell)))`. I haven't tested this, 'tho.

Answer (score 3):

I use **dired** to access the remote machine and open a shell there.

Here is the function I use, taken and modified from [Tikhon Jelviss' emacs configuration](http://www.quora.com/What-does-Tikhon-Jelviss-Emacs-setup-look-like):

```
(defun anr-shell (buffer)
  "Opens a new shell buffer where the given buffer is located."
  (interactive "sBuffer: ")
  (pop-to-buffer (concat "*" buffer "*"))
  (unless (eq major-mode 'shell-mode)
    (dired buffer)
    (shell buffer)
    (sleep-for 0 200)
    (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
    (comint-simple-send (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)) 
                        (concat "export PS1=\"\033[33m" buffer "\033[0m:\033[35m\\W\033[0m>\""))))
```

Example:

```
(anr-shell "/vagrant@localhost#2222:/vagrant/")
```

Comment: Please repost the answer here, as links to the actual answer is discouraged to avoid link rot

Comment: The answer has been reposted.

Comment: Vote changed accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Although not made overly clear in the manual `C-u M-x shell` allows you to specify the name of the shell buffer, ***and*** more importantly in your case allows you to specify the `Default directory`, which can take a string just like Tramp `/ssh:server:/my/path`.

An alternative is to open dired (`C-x d`) rather than an actual file, if you `M-x shell` from directory, the shell opens with the context of the dired directory.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

1. `M-x cd` to change the buffer's default directory to the desired remote directory
2. invoke `M-x shell`, which will open a shell on the remote machine